# DNN Search: Indexing, what to index, and filters

Tags: search, dotnetnuke

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how the search function works for DNN. To begin, I only have **admin** credentials to the site (I know this already limits what I can do with search).

I will be putting a large document on the site, and I want it to be indexed with a search function that will allow filtered search. The document will be put into the FAQs module and arranged in a tree-structure hierarchy. Any ideas on how indexing specific modules may work, and how to get the search function to work with filters? I downloaded the Enhanced Search module, but learned that doesn't do much for searching with filters.

Thank you, any leads would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is not possible with the combination of elements that you have noted.  (DNN + FAQ Module).

You have a few options available to you that might be able to make this more of a reality, but it will require more control overall of the installation.

1. Use a third party module such as Document Exchange which allows you to search/index within files
2. Use DotNetNuke Professional Editions "Spider" to crawl the site rather than using a regular index process that comes with CE.

Comment: Yes I just learned this will not work... Thanks for the suggestions. On a related note, is there a DNN module that will take a PDF file with a Table of Contents that is linked to certain subcomponents, and automatically convert that into a hierarchic online document with the same menu?

Comment: Evotiva DNNUserFiles also allows you to search/index within files